# Android update ONE marker ONLY in Mapview, how?

Tags: android

Is there a way to update one of my marker's position on a mapview?

How?

thanks,
Leslie

Comment: can you present us some of your code ?? When you want to update marker??

Answer (score 0):

```
 public final class CustomdOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {
     void setPoint(GeoPoint point) {
         mPoint = point;
     }
 }
```

And do not forget to call populate() and draw() methods in your ItemizedOverlay after this thing.

Maybe more useful and safer would be remove previous OverlayItem object, create new one with appropriate coordinates and then apply it to your map?